# How to implement transactional MessageStore strategy in spring integration?

Tags: jdbc, spring-integration

My publisher component publishes messages to a jdbc message store backed queue channel. My requirement is that the messages should not be delivered to the queue if the publisher thread encounters an exception.
I would like to make use of weblogic JTA transaction manager.

Pls advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages publishing honors the transactions, if any in the caller thread. 
There is no special setting required.